# Sql error : Invalid use of group function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I want to select a row with max ID(primary key) value having patient_id=xyz

following is my sql script

```
check="Select * from notes where id=max(ID) in (SELECT * FROM notes WHERE patient_id="+patientSoapBean.getPatientID()+")";
```

I am getting invalid use of group function error. can you point out the error in this.

Comment: i got this one solved by what @Mike Brant suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely are trying to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM notes
WHERE patient_id = ?
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: using what you suggested    I am getting following error :com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: i entered :      check=" SELECT * FROM notes WHERE patient_id ="+patientSoapBean.getPatientID()+"ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
an I am using MySQL if that helps

Comment: my bad I missed a space before order.